# Linking to a CSS stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I'm kind of a newbie to html and definitely to CSS.  I'm learning from the book Foundation Website Creation with CSS, XHTML, and JavaScript, which I understand is old at the time of this question, but still hoping I can help many.  Here is my markup:

```
 <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
     charset=utf-8"/>
     <title>Welcome to Papa Pepperoncini's</title>
     <link  href="C:\Users\Kevin Turner\Desktop\html\indexcss.css" rel="stylesheet"          type="text/css"/>
 </head>
```

Why isn't my stylesheet linking?  Am I allowed to make this link?  What should I do?  I believe it's working in Chrome, but not in IE or Firefox, perhaps you could help me understand this also.

Thanks, 
Kevin

Comment: I'd check the filename(indexcss.css is suspicious) if I were you .. and use `relative` path to link a file

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `C:\Users\Kevin Turner\Desktop\html\indexcss.css`. This is not a correct URL. Usually you'd use a relative URL path. If your the file including the css is in the same directory, just write the filename.

This should work if the file is in the same directory (folder) as your html-file:

```
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
     charset=utf-8"/>
     <title>Welcome to Papa Pepperoncini's</title>
     <link  href="indexcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
```

---

To explain what a `relative URL path` is, imagine you've got a folder structure like this:

```
 --- html/
 ----- index.html
 ----- css/
 ------- maincss.css
```

and you want to include the `maincss.css`-file in your `index.html`. Then you'd do 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/maincss.css" />`. Because `maincss.css` is in the `css/` directory (folder), which is relative to the directory you're in (`html/`).

---

You can use `file:///c:/Users/Kevin%20Turner/Desktop/html/indexcss.css`
[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme). But *ONLY* if the css-file is located on the computer that you are loading the page on!

---

So. if the CSS-file is in the same directory as the file including it (probably `index.html`), your code would be:

```
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
     charset=utf-8"/>
     <title>Welcome to Papa Pepperoncini's</title>
     <link  href="indexcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
```

---

And the other, with the `file:///` URI and the file is located on the computer loading the html-page, would look like

```
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
     charset=utf-8"/>
     <title>Welcome to Papa Pepperoncini's</title>
     <link  href="file:///c:/Users/Kevin%20Turner/Desktop/html/indexcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
```

Comment: Here we go.. Let the `w3schools` bashing begin !

Comment: Am I not supposed to? I will improve the answer and write more about it.

Comment: Noo Nooo !! People who post `links` or `tutorials` to `w3schools` will be generally humiliated here and they have their own reasons for it !

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the heads up! Is it just the w3schools? Or is it beginner-tutorial sites in general?

Comment: Fixed the link-removal. This answer is okay i assume?

Answer (score 0):

Standard CSS link declaration goes something like this:

`<head>
     <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "cssdoc.css">
</head`

There is probably something wrong with the path you entered. In the future, consider having both the HTML doc that you're editing. and the CSS document on desktop(or just in the same folder). that way you don't have to type in the full path every time (assuming you're just using a simple Notepad-like editor)

Answer (score 0):

Before the your local URL type `file:///`

Answer (score 0):

As your file is stored locally, make sure you use the `file:///` URI scheme:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C:\Users\Kevin Turner\Desktop\html\indexcss.css" />
```

**Still not working?**

Some (or most?) browsers block access to your local file system, even when the webpage itself runs locally. This is a security measure to prevent webpages from accessing and modifying your local files.

Chrome, for instance, will return an error saying something like `Not allowed to load local resource`. To fix this on Windows, you have to launch Chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag. Simply close Chrome, right click and modify the shortcut, add the flag at the end of the shortcut target. So your target would be something like this: `C:\path\to\chrome\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`. This will allow Chrome to access your local stylesheets.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? I've updated my answer with a possible solution. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't link to a local file because on your live website this won't work.  Even if your filesystem is set up the same way, the HTTP server probably won't serve it.  It also depends on how your HTML is being served locally (by a server or just with files).

Anyway, you should link to the CSS file relative to the html file or preferably the document root (the folder that is serving your website files).  If you can figure out your document root, you could use:

```
<link href="/indexcss.css">
```

...assuming that your document root is at something like

```
C:\Users\Kevin Turner\Desktop\html\
```

If your html file (with the `<head>`) is in the same folder as `indexcss.css`, you can just use

```
<link href="indexcss.css">
```

Make sure that you understand the document root and relative/absolute paths.